# Tools to visualise Android layout xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am coming from the iOS background so I miss my interface builder in Android. I am not sure if there is a good and trustworthy LayoutPreview tool (could be free or paid) that can help us to open the xml file to preview it when we are working. The current process is to finish the xml file, compile the code and run it on the real Android device.

The Android Studio Layout tools is not always accurate and I am looking for a better tool

This is just taking much time for some simple change.

Answer (score 2):

[Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html), software based off of IntelliJ, will show you a preview of any XML file you make it it, like shown below.

In addition to being able to preview XML files, Android Studio is also a full-functioned IDE customized for developing Android applications. It is a step up from Eclipse, in my opinion, and so is IntelliJ in general

[image]

Comment: http://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/

Answer (score 0):

There is a layout editor built into both of the standard Android IDEs (Android Studio, and Eclipse).  You can access it from any XML layout file via a tab on the bottom of the file (you can switch between visual editor, and the raw XML)